# linked list buffer ; what should insert return?

Tags: c++

Forgive me if this question have been here before.

i had written working void insert function to linked list, but i have to make function working with:

```
CyclicBuffer cbof4(4);
 cbof4.insert(1).insert(2).insert(3).insert(4);
```

this is my class:

```
class node
{
friend class CyclicBuffer;
public:
    int value;
    node* next;
    node(int data)
    {
        next = NULL;
        value = data;
    }
};

class CyclicBuffer
{
private:
    int _size;
    node *head;
    node *tail;
public:
    void insert(int data);
    void extract();
    bool empty();
    bool full();
    int used();
    void print();
    CyclicBuffer(int size)
    {
        _size = size;
        head = NULL;
        tail = NULL;
    }
};
```

and my insert function:

```
void CyclicBuffer::insert(int data)
{
    node *p = new node(data);
    p -> next = NULL;

    if (tail == NULL)
    {
        tail = head = p;
    }
    else
    {
        head -> next =  p;
        head = p;
    }
}
```

Can someone give me some advice what my function should return ?

Comment: but void function don't work with
cbof4.insert(1).insert(2).insert(3).insert(4);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to chain like that, the easiest would be to just return itself:

```
CyclicBuffer& CyclicBuffer::insert(int data) {
    // rest as before
    return *this;
}
```

That way,

```
cbof4.insert(1).insert(2).insert(3).insert(4);
```

is exactly the same as

```
cbof4.insert(1);
cbof4.insert(2);
cbof4.insert(3);
cbof4.insert(4);
```